# Minicart Problem in Custom Module in Magento 2

Tags: cart, magento-2.1, addtocart, shopping-cart, mini-cart

I am working on **Quick Order Custom Module**, for this I have shown the all products in to one page. So that the customer will add the multiple product to cart at a time. Here Products are adding to cart and showing messages in my form, but `minicart` is not showing. For this I have written below code.

**quickorder.phtml**

```
<?php

$list = $block->getProducts();

$cart_items = $block->getCartItems();

?>

<div style="width: 100%;">
    <h3>Quick Order Instructions</h3>
    <div>
        <p>The <b>Quick Order</b> page is designed to simplify the ordering process.
            All products are listed in the table below. A search feature has been provided to help find the desired product(s).
            In addition, the table headers are sortable on devices with a screen width greater than 550px.
        </p>
        <div >
            <h4 style="margin-bottom:5px">How to use the Quick Order Page</h4>
            <ol style="margin-left: 35px;">
                <li>Find the desired product(s), using the search feature if needed. </li>
                <li>Enter the amount into <b>QTY</b> box and press enter or select the <b>ADD TO CART</b> button.</li>
                <li>View the cart to place your order -or- continue shopping on the page.</li>
            </ol>
            <p>*<b>Best Price</b> is calculated on largest quantity discount.</p>
        </div>


    </div>

</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$baseURL_l = $social_image_url = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();

$fav = "";
$sk = "";
$name = "";
$price = "";
$qty = "";
$cart = "";

if(count($list) > 0 ){
    /*$table = "";*/
    foreach($list as $items){

        $product_obj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($items->getId());

        $sku = $product_obj->getSKU();
        $url = $baseURL_l . $sku;

        $fav .= "<p>";
        $fav .= "<center>&nbsp</center>";
        $fav .= "</p>";

        $sk .= "<p>";
        $sk .= "<a href='$url' target='_blank'>";
        $sk .= $sku;
        $sk .= "</a>";
        $sk .= "</p>";

        $name .= "<p>";
        $name .= $product_obj->getName();
        $name .= "</p>";

        $price_for = number_format($product_obj->getPrice(), 2, '.', '');

        $price .= "<p>";
        $price .= $price_for;
        $price .= "</p>";

        $qty .= "<p>";
        //$qty .= "<input type='text' style='text-align:center;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;width:40px;height: 20px;' maxLength='3' id='Quantity_$sku' name='Quantity' value=''>";
        $qty .= "<input type='number' maxLength='3' name='qty_$sku' id='qty' title='Qty' value='' class='input-text qty' style='text-align:center;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;width:40px;height: 20px;'/>";
        $qty .= "</p>";

        $cart .= "<p>";
        $cart .= "<center>&nbsp</center>";
        $cart .= "</p>";


    }
}

if(count($list) >0 ){
    $div = "";
    $div .= "<div class='row'>";
    $div .= "<div class='custom_fav' style='background-color:lavenderblush;'>";
    $div .= "<h3>Favorites</h3>";
    $div .= $fav;
    $div .= "</div>";
    $div .= "<div class='custom_sku' style='background-color:lavenderblush;'>";
    $div .= "<h3>SKU</h3>";
    $div .= $sk;
    $div .= "</div>";
    $div .= "<div class='custom_name' style='background-color:lavenderblush;'>";
    $div .= "<h3>Product Name</h3>";
    $div .= $name;
    $div .= "</div>";
    $div .= "<div class='custom_price' style='background-color:lavenderblush;'>";
    $div .= "<h3>Best Price</h3>";
    $div .= $price;
    $div .= "</div>";
    $div .= "<div class='custom_text' style='background-color:lavenderblush;'>";
    $div .= "<h3>Qty</h3>";
    $div .= $qty;
    $div .= "</div>";
    $div .= "<div class='custom_cart_qty' style='background-color:lavenderblush;'>";
    $div .= "<h3>In Cart</h3>";
    $div .= $cart;
    $div .= "</div>";

    $div .= "</div>";

   ?>

<form data-role="tocart-form" method="post" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $baseURL_l . 'quickorder/index/add'; ?>">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="submit" onclick="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $baseURL_l . 'quickorder/index/add'; ?>" name="insert" value="Add to Cart" class="btn" />
        <button type="submit"
                title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                class="btn">
        </button>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: right;">
        <input type='text' style='text-align:center;padding-right:1px;padding-left:1px;width:350px;height: 30px;' id='search' name='search' value=''>
        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Product Search" class="btn" onclick="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $baseURL_l . 'quickorder/index/search'; ?>"/>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <?php echo $div; ?>
    <br/>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Add to Cart" class="btn" onclick="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $baseURL_l . 'quickorder/index/add'; ?>"/>
    </div>
</form>
    <?php
}else{
    $div = "";
    $div .= "<div class='row'>";
    $div .= "<div class='custom_fav' style='background-color:lavenderblush;'>";
    $div .= "<h3>Favorites</h3>";
    $div .= "<p>No Records Found!</p>";
    $div .= "</div>";
    $div .= "<div class='custom_sku' style='background-color:lavenderblush;'>";
    $div .= "<h3>SKU</h3>";
    $div .= "<p>!</p>";
    $div .= "</div>";
    $div .= "<div class='custom_name' style='background-color:lavenderblush;'>";
    $div .= "<h3>Product Name</h3>";
    $div .= "<p>!</p>";
    $div .= "</div>";
    $div .= "<div class='custom_price' style='background-color:lavenderblush;'>";
    $div .= "<h3>Best Price</h3>";
    $div .= "<p>!</p>";
    $div .= "</div>";
    $div .= "<div class='custom_text' style='background-color:lavenderblush;'>";
    $div .= "<h3>Qty</h3>";
    $div .= "<p>!</p>";
    $div .= "</div>";
    $div .= "<div class='custom_cart_qty' style='background-color:lavenderblush;'>";
    $div .= "<h3>In Cart</h3>";
    $div .= "<p>!</p>";
    $div .= "</div>";
    $div .= "</div>";

    echo $div;

}

?>
```

**Add.php** controller

```
/**
     * Add product to shopping cart action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        $request = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        try {


            $sku_list = [];

            foreach($request as $k => $v){
                if (strpos($k, 'qty_') !== false) {
                    $sku = explode('_',$k);
                    if($v !="" || $v !=0)
                        $sku_list[$sku[1]] = $v;
                }
            }

            $product = $this->_productFactory->create();

            foreach($sku_list as $k => $v){

                $data = $product->loadByAttribute('sku',$k);
                $product = $this->_initProduct1($data->getId());

                /**
                 * Check product availability
                 */
                if (!$product) {
                    return $this->goBack();
                }

                $requests = array('product' => $product->getId(),'qty' => $v);
                $_product = $this->productRepository->getById($product->getId());
                $qty = $v;

                if($_product->getTypeId() == "bundle"){

                    //
                    $productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
                    $requiredChildrenIds = $productTypeInstance->getChildrenIds($_product->getId(), true);

                    $par = array('product' => $product->getId(),
                        "bundle_options" => array(),
                        'qty' => $v);
                    $magento = [];
                    foreach($requiredChildrenIds as $child){
                        $i =0;
                        foreach($child as $k => $v){
                            $i++;
                            $prod = $this->productRepository->getById($v);
                            $isSaleable = $prod->isSalable();
                            if($isSaleable){
                                $magento[$v] = "$i";
                            }else{
                                $message = __('No stock for this Item',$_product->getName());
                                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($message);
                                return $this->goBack(null, $product);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    $par = array(
                        'product' => $product->getId(),
                        'bundle_options' => array(  1 => $magento),
                        'qty' => $qty
                    );

                    $this->cart->addProduct($_product,$par);

                }else{
                    $this->cart->addProduct($_product,$requests);
                }



                $message = __('You added %1 to your shopping cart.',$product->getName());
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($message);

            }

            $this->cart->save();

            return $resultRedirect->setPath('quickorder/index/index');

        }  catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            return $this->goBack();
        }
    }
```

After adding product to shopping cart showing success message see below pic[image].

and not showing the red icon in `minicart` see above pic. When I navigate browser to cart page showing products in cart page. But I con is not showing.

Any suggestings or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my self by adding below code.

add `section.xml` to `etc/frontend`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="[frontName]/[ActionPath]/[ActionName]">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```